# Monty Hall Style bag of marbles problem

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Inspired by question $7a$ on the Euclid Maths competition $2023$, I have been stuck thinking about the following simplified version.

A bag contains $2$ blue marbles and $1$ red marble. You remove one at a time until the bag is empty. Each marble is chosen randomly from the remaining marbles. Given that the second marble removed is blue, what is the probability that the final marble removed is blue?

I have been presented with what appears to be two logical explanations with different answers.

1. Given the second marble is blue there are only two scenarios. The first marble is blue and the final marble is red, or the first marble is red and the final marble is blue. Thus the probability that the final marble is blue is $1/2$.
2. Notice that this question is equivalent to asking, what is the probability that the first marble picked is red. When the first marble is picked there are $2$ blue marbles, and $1$ red marble in the bag. Thus the probability that the first marble picked is red is $1/3$.

I am not sure whether this is a simple conditional probability question as explanation $1$ suggests, the Monty Hall problem in disguise as explanation $2$ suggests, or an ambiguously worded question that relies on interpretation of the language.

If anyone could provide some insight into why either one of the explanations is correct or incorrect it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Ummmm.... if you've removed two marbles, you know *FOR CERTAIN* what the remaining marble is.  See?

Comment: Even if explanation 2 were correct (which it is not), this still would not be "the Monty Hall problem in disguise." It takes more than just coming up with the same answer -- or even having the same naive wrong answer and the same counterintuitive correct answer -- to make two problems equivalent. You must also show how each detail of the mechanics of one problem matches a corresponding detail of the other problem. And you have not shown any evidence that there is such a correspondence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Monty Hall type of situation here.

The flaw in your reasoning is that for number 2., the question is *not* equivalent to merely asking if the first marble is red.  It is instead asking if the first marble is red, **conditioned on the fact that the second marble picked was blue**.  This conditional probability is given by

$$P(\text{first red}|\text{second blue})= \frac{P(\text{first red and second blue})}{P(\text{second blue})} = \frac{1/3}{2/3}=\frac{1}{2}\text{.}$$

Thus the two approaches do yield the same probability, once interpreted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I was getting confused because I was thinking of the Monty Hall problem in the following way: 

Suppose you have 3 doors and behind 2 of the doors is a blue marble, and behind one of the doors is a red marble. You are asked to randomly select a door, knowing that afterwards the host will select a different door revealing a blue marble. What is the probability that a blue marble is behind the door that has not yet been selected? 

Is this formulation different to the one above? Why or why not?

Comment: The difference here is that the hosts action is not random (at least, not necessarily random - he might pick randomly but only if there are two blues to choose from), whereas in your problem above, all three marbles were guaranteed to be chosen completely randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Our total sample space $\Omega$ is $RBB,BRB,BBR$. If we know the second one is blue, then the restricted sample space is $RBB, BBR$. As you noted, each has same probability so we get $50\%$, so your first interpretation is correct.

The second interpretation is problematic because you are discarding information. It is true that picking red first implies the last marble picked will be blue and the second marble will be blue.

However, the outcome $BRB$ also has us picking the blue marble last but it is inconsistent with our knowledge that the second marble is blue, therefore, we are back to only $RBB, BBR$ as the only part of the sample space consistent with *all* of our information.